# django postgresql opposite list search

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, lookup

Good afternoon

I am using django with postgresql for an application.

I have a model that contains a field which is a charfield and stores *none/one/many* references to external databases.

- If *none* it is empty
- If *one* it is the reference itself ("CCCC")
- If *many* it is each reference separated by semicolons ("AAAA;BBBB;CCCC;DDDD;EEEE;"). This can be seen below:

An example of the python file of the model can be found below:

```
Models.py file:

class Data(models.Model):
    ...
    external_database_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
```

The reason for using a charfield was that, at the beggining, all this information was only to display it to the user, and no other option was applied on it.

Now I need to implement/apply a lookup filter with django. I have an array containing some references:

```
For example: [AAAA,BBBB,EEEE]
```

I need to know if the any entry on the database matches to any of the entries of this list

So far I have tried the "external_database_id__in" lookup filter "https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in". It works in the case of the "*none*" and "*one*" but not in the "*many*", since there is no match for the whole string to the list...

- *none*: "" in [AAAA,BBBB,EEEE] --> FALSE (as expected)
- *one*: "CCCC" in [AAAA,BBBB,EEEE] --> FALSE (as expected)
- *one*: "EEEE" in [AAAA,BBBB,EEEE] --> TRUE (as expected)
- *many*: "AAAA;BBBB;" in [AAAA,BBBB,EEEE] --> FALSE (as expected, but undesired, since TRUE would be the correct answer)
- *many*: "AAAA;CCCC;" in [AAAA,BBBB,EEEE] --> FALSE (as expected, but undesired, since TRUE would be the correct answer)
- *many*: "CCCC;DDDD;" in [AAAA,BBBB,EEEE] --> FALSE (as expected)

I have thought to do the opposite, but couldn't find the way to do it in django or postgresql:

- *none*: any[AAAA,BBBB,EEEE] in "" --> FALSE
- *one*: any[AAAA,BBBB,EEEE] in "CCCC" --> FALSE
- *one*: any[AAAA,BBBB,EEEE] in "EEEE" --> TRUE
- *many*: any[AAAA,BBBB,EEEE] in "AAAA;BBBB;" --> TRUE
- *many*: any[AAAA,BBBB,EEEE] in "AAAA;CCCC;" --> TRUE
- *many*: any[AAAA,BBBB,EEEE] in "CCCC;DDDD;" --> FALSE

Any ideas?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with regular Python

```
# Using Python3.4
sample = "AAAA;BBBB;"
full = ["AAAA","BBBB","EEEE"]

bool([x for x in sample.split(";") if x in full])

>> True
```

As long as the full array does not contain an empty string, this will work.

The elements in the `full` array weren't quoted in your example but I had to do that to make it work. Not sure how that affects what you are doing.

Comment: The problem is that this needs to be done in a postgresql level... since all data is stored in a database...